# Calculating intake rate with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to calculate the intake rate of several species for a large dataset and I have been continually running into errors. I want to be able to search the dataset for a specific species and then calculate the intake rate in a new column based on the Density data found in the dataset and then apply it to a user defined equation with a list of constants. When running the code I wrote I receive the error: `Error in if (bd$Density[i] < max) { :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning message: In Ops.factor(bd$Density[i], max) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors`
I am not sure if this is the best way to achieve my goal, but here is what I have so far:

```
  bd<-biomass_data[,7:9]
> bd<-sample_n(bd,30)
> bd<-as.matrix(bd)
> dput(bd)
structure(c("Scirpus robustus?", "Scirpus genus 1", "Zannichallia palustris", 
"Hydrobia", "Scirpus subterminalis", "Scirpus genus 1", "Scirpus americanus", 
"Scirpus genus 2", "Scirpus validus", "Scirpus genus", "Scirpus genus", 
"Scirpus heterochaetus", "Scirpus heterochaetus", "Scirpus olney?", 
"Scirpus subterminalis", "Zannichallia palustris", "Spartina pectinata", 
"Melampus bidentatus", "Melampus bidentatus", "Spartina genus", 
"Scirpus validus", "Scirpus americanus", "Hydrobia spp", "Scirpus robustus", 
"Scirpus genus 3", "Zannichallia palustris", "Spartina genus?", 
"Scirpus americanus", "Scirpus olneyi", "Scirpus genus 3", "0.001426029", 
"0.000519737", "5.72E-05", "3.57E-06", "2.44E-05", "0.002040368", 
"0.000558061", "0.020121403", "0.00034925", "1.87E-05", "1.12E-05", 
"6.98E-05", "0.000524448", "0.000963843", "3.63E-05", "2.16E-06", 
"3.31E-06", "0.000127069", "0.004839333", "0.000101477", "4.84E-06", 
"9.03E-05", "1.03E-05", "9.33E-05", "3.69E-05", "7.17E-05", "0.000152916", 
"9.52E-05", "0.01200946", "1.20E-05", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Zannichellia", 
"Melampus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", 
"Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", 
"Zannichellia", "Scirpus", "Melampus", "Melampus", "Scirpus", 
"Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Melampus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Zannichellia", 
"Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus", "Scirpus"), .Dim = c(30L, 3L
), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Prey", "Density", "Prey.Group")))


f2<-function(x,a,b){return((a*x)/(b+x))}
f3<-function(x,a,b){return((a*x)^2/(b^2+x^2))}

for(i in 1:nrow(bd)){
  if(bd$Prey.Group[i]=="Melampus"){
    #mytype = 2
    a=0.01025
    b=3.76698
    max = 6
    imax =0.007
    if(bd$Density[i]<max){
      bd$intakerate[i] = f2(bd$Density[i],a,b)
    }
    else{
      bd$intakerate[i] = imax
    }
  }
  else if(bd$Prey.Group[i]=="Zannichellia"){
    #mytype = 2
    a=1.489
    b=701.753
    max = 1600
    imax = 1
    if(bd$Density[i]<max){
      bd$intakerate[i] = f2(bd$Density[i],a,b)
    }
    else{
      bd$intakerate[i] = imax
    }
  }
  else if(bd$Prey.Group[i]=="Scirpus"){
    #mytype = 3
    a=0.1644
    b=-10.9602
    max = 40
    imax = 0.03
    if(bd$Density[i]<max){
      bd$intakerate[i] = f3(bd$Density[i],a,b)
    }
    else{
      bd$intakerate[i] = imax
    }
  }
  else if(bd$Prey.Group[i]=="Ruppia"){
    #mytype = 2
    a=1.1318
    b=434.9
    max=1500
    imax = 1.4
    if(bd$Density[i]<max){
      bd$intakerate[i] =  f2(bd$Density[i],a,b)
    }
    else{
      bd$intakerate[i] = imax
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
library('data.table')
# create constant table for each species. I did for only two species, but you can do the same for all species.
spec_const <- data.frame(Prey.Group = c('Melampus',"Zannichellia"),
                         a = c(0.01025, 1.489),
                         b = c(3.76698, 701.753),
                         max = c(6, 1600),
                         imax = c(0.007, 1),
                         fun = c(2, 3),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# convert bd to data table
bd <- as.data.table(bd)
# convert spec_const to data table
setDT(spec_const)
# tidy data: Density from character to numeric
bd[, Density := as.numeric(Density)]
# assign imax value to intake_rate for each of their Prey.Group
bd[spec_const, on = "Prey.Group", intake_rate := imax ]
# apply functions 2 and 3 based on the join results of bd and spec_const
# rbind them together
rbindlist(l = list(bd[spec_const[fun == 2,], on = "Prey.Group" ][Density < max, intake_rate := f2(Density, a, b) ][],
                   bd[spec_const[fun == 3,], on = "Prey.Group" ][Density < max, intake_rate := f3(Density, a, b) ][]))

#                      Prey     Density   Prey.Group  intake_rate       a         b  max  imax fun
# 1:               Hydrobia 0.000003570     Melampus 9.714006e-09 0.01025   3.76698    6 0.007   2
# 2:    Melampus bidentatus 0.000127069     Melampus 3.457447e-07 0.01025   3.76698    6 0.007   2
# 3:    Melampus bidentatus 0.004839333     Melampus 1.315099e-05 0.01025   3.76698    6 0.007   2
# 4:           Hydrobia spp 0.000010300     Melampus 2.802635e-08 0.01025   3.76698    6 0.007   2
# 5: Zannichallia palustris 0.000057200 Zannichellia 1.473034e-14 1.48900 701.75300 1600 1.000   3
# 6: Zannichallia palustris 0.000002160 Zannichellia 2.100527e-17 1.48900 701.75300 1600 1.000   3
# 7: Zannichallia palustris 0.000071700 Zannichellia 2.314510e-14 1.48900 701.75300 1600 1.000   3
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for your help.

Comment: The function bd[, Density := as.numeric(Density)]